# How to map URL to follow folder scheme in ASP.NET Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

I have this folder layout:

```
Pages
|
|- index.cshtml
|- products.cshtml
|- products
           |
           |- product1.cshtml
           |- product2.cshtml
|- settings.cshtml
```

The root folders work perfectly (`index.cshtml`, `products.cshtml`, `settings.cshtml`) and the URL maps respectivley, for example `products.cshtml` will map to `https://example.com/products`

I'd like the `.cshtml` files in the `products` subfolder of the `Pages` folder to map like this too. For example, `product1.cshtml` maps to the URL `https://example.com/products/product1` etc.

Currently in each product file I have `@page "/products/product1"` which I do not know if it is the correct way, it seems to half work but has weird behaviour if there is a trailing `/` on the end of the URL, CSS isnt loaded etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a custom [Page route action convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-2.1#page-route-action-conventions).

The example code is as follows：

```
 services.AddRazorPages(options =>
                {
                    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/products/product1", " product1");
                    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/products/ product2", " product2");
                    options.Conventions.AddFolderRouteModelConvention("/", model =>
                    {
                        var selectorCount = model.Selectors.Count;
                        for (var i = selectorCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                        {
                            var selectorTemplate = model.Selectors[i].AttributeRouteModel.Template;
 
                            if (selectorTemplate.StartsWith("products")) 
                                model.Selectors.RemoveAt(i);
                        }
                    });
                });
```